# Why does the counter print 4 instead of 5?

Tags: python

```
vowels = 'aeiou'
str = 'a quick brown fox'

def count_vowels(string):
    total = 0
    for v in vowels:
        if v in string:
            total += 1
    print(total)

count_vowels(str)
```

I do not understand why this block of code prints 4 instead of 5. But when i used:

```
for c in string:
    if c in vowels:
        total += 1
```

It gives me a result of 5. Really appreciate the help here.

Comment: Well, there's no "e" in that string.

Comment: because the loops are doing two different things? The first loop counts how many characters in `vowels` are in `'a quick brown fox'`, the other loop does the opposite, it counts how many characters in `'a quick brown fox'` are in `vowels`. Did you expect these to be the same?

Comment: Why were you expecting 5? Kraigolas's explanation seems likely, but so does user2357112's. You can [edit] to clarify. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga bloody genius mate, appreciate the breakdown. Understood this fully now.

Answer (score 3):

In the second loop, you can count the vowel `o` twice because it occurs twice in `string`. In the first example, you only consider `o` once because it only occurs in `vowels` once. That's what's causing the difference.

---

My recommendation here would be either using a debugger, or a simple print statement:

```
def count_vowels(string):
    total = 0
    for v in vowels:
        if v in string:
            print(v)
            total += 1
    print(total)

count_vowels(str)
```

Which gives

```
a
i
o
u
4 # this is the final count, not a vowel
```

and

```
for c in string:
    if c in vowels:
        print(c)
        total += 1
```

which gives

```
a
u
i
o
o
```

this would've revealed the difference to you without needing to pose a question at all.

---

One final note: don't use `str` as a variable name. `str` has a meaning in Python, and when you name a variable `str` you can no longer use it for its intended use.